# How are plage regions related to the density of medium and velocity FeII ions?

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, the-sun, data-analysis, spectra

During a [literature review](https://www.academia.edu/37785178/THEORETICAL_MODELLING_OF_CHROMOSPHERIC_EMISSION_LINES_THROUGH_THE_SOLAR_ACTIVITY_CYCLES_21_23_ACCORDING_TO_THE_OBSERVATIONAL_ANALYSIS_RESULTS?source=swp_share) ([abstract](https://inis.iaea.org/search/searchsinglerecord.aspx?recordsFor=SingleRecord&RN=50003604)), I found that the intensity of FeII (298.5 nm) ions in the last solar minimum was higher than the two previous solar minima 21 & 22. The velocity of FeII ions increases with decreasing density of the medium and increasing plage surfaces/region.

How are plage regions related to the density of medium and velocity FeII ions?

Comment: I have now edited the question, pls find the relevant paper

Comment: @uhoh now I have linked the paper, pls check

Comment: That's great, thanks! :-)